# Disconnecting two socket connections made by user on browser tab close

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am working on a socket.io based video conference project where every time a user joins the room, at most two socket connections will be made, one for video/audio transmission(default) and the other for screen sharing(optional). For the socket network, this looks like video/audio is coming from one user and screen sharing is from a different user. But they are actually the same user making two different socket connections and streaming them separately.

I have read in the socket.io documentation that when the browser tab is closed, the socket connection made will be closed automatically and a "disconnect" event is emitted. This disconnect event is caught by the socket server in the backend and is broadcasted to all other users in the room, saying this particular user has left.

But here in my case where there can be two socket connections, browser tab close is triggering only one of the connections' "disconnect" event and the other connection is still not being disconnected.

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.emit("connected", socket.id);

  socket.on("join-room", (roomId, sockId) => {   
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log(`Broadcasting disconnected event of ${sockId}`);
      socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit("disconnected", sockId);
    });
  });
})
```

How to make the closing of the browser tab, disconnect both the socket connections made by the user?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a listener on client-side which listens to the "disconnected" event and handle disconnection.

```
    socket.on("disconnected", (socketId) => {
       // handle disconnection
       alert(`Userid: ${socketId} has disconnected`);     
       socket.disconnect(); // Manually disconnects the socket
  });
```

Comment: I already did that, I am able to disconnect if a "disconnect" event is caught by the socket server. But the disconnect event itself is not being triggered for the second connection made., i.e. the screen sharing part of the connection.

Comment: how is the screen sharing implemented?

Comment: It is implemented like a normal socket connection as let scrSocket = io.connect("/"); and rest follows the call implementation

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link but this seems to be a different problem. My problem is about browser close. In my case disconnect event is being emitted to the server and caught back on the client side of all users.  But it is happening only with one of the two connections, so only one connection is getting disconnected.